# How do you find the automorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, automorphism-group

How exactly would you find all the automorphism of something like $Z_8$ or $U(8)$?

---

I read that there are $4$ automorphisms of $Z_8$, but how did they come about it?

Please explain this as if talking to a beginner. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In the case of $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$, a homomorphism is determined by where it sends a generator, and an automorphism must send generators to generators. What are the generators? Work from there.

In the case of $U(8)=(\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z)^\times$, automorphisms permute elements of the same order, and this groups has three elements of order three. Find out which permutations are possible.

Comment: Generators of Z_8 are 1,3,5,7.  So since there are 4, that means the auto of Z_8 would be 4?  What exactly does it mean that sends "generators to generators"?

Comment: @otter69 4 is a number, not an automorphism. The phrase "sends generators to generators" means that if $x$ is a generator and $\alpha$ an automorphism then $\alpha(x)$ is also a generator. (So, in fact, the generators are sent to generators, exactly as described.)

Comment: U(8) has 1,2,4 and only 2 has order 3 in U(8)

Comment: @otter69 Neither 2 nor 4 are elements of U(8). Before you try to find the automorphisms of U(8) you should try to know what it is first!

Comment: Would it be correct to say, since 1 is a generator of Z_8, we'd have x generate to x?  Which would be an automorphism since it's 1-1?

Comment: Then for 3, it would be x to 3x which would equal 3,6,1,4,7,2,5,0, which would also map 1-1 to Z_8

Comment: `we'd have x generate to x` you mean the map $x\mapsto x$ would be an automorphism. Yes, that's correct (and the identity map is always an automorphism in every group). And for the generator $3$, the map $x\mapsto3x$ is also an automorphism on $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$, as you've checked. There is also $x\mapsto 5x$ and $x\mapsto 7x$, as the generators of $\Bbb Z/8\Bbb Z$ are $1,3,5,7$.

Comment: And then for U(8) generators would be 1,3,5,7?  x to 3x would be 3,1 which would not be an automorphism.  And x to 5x would be 5, 1 and x to 7x would be 7,1 which are not an automorphism on U(8).  So the generators of U(8) would not be an automorphism?

Comment: @otter69 Since U(8) is not cyclic we cannot use the same reasoning. That is why I gave a different approach in the second half of my answer for that problem.

Comment: When you ask which permutations are possible, do you mean what are the 3 elements have order 3?

Comment: Nope. There are three elements of order two in U(8), namely 3,5,7. Which permutations on the set {3,5,7} amount to an automorphism on U(8)? (In fact, all six of them do.)

Comment: I'm not sure..I'm drawing a blank

Comment: Check by hand that each permutation is an automorphism. This doesn't require cleverness, only checking things.

Comment: I haven't read much about automorphism except that that it's an isomorphism to itself.  I will see if I can find anything about permutations relation to autos.  Thanks.

Comment: @otter69 Well, an automorphism is a bijection on a set that is also a homomorphism. A bijection on a set is called a permutation, all you need to do is check which are homomorphisms.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to check which are homomorphisms..

Comment: To check if an X is a Y, you see if X satisfies the definition of being a Y.

Comment: 3, 5,7 all have order 2, and I think 4 has order 2 as well.  1 has order 8.  2,6 has order 3.  6 has order 3.  Would that mean 3,4,5,7 are homomorphism of one other since they have the same order which implies 1-1?

Comment: Do you know what U(8) is? It only has four elements. You need to understand what U(8) is before you try to figure out its automorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

This entry is full of hints...maybe a fuller answer would be useful?

$U(8)$ has the operation of multiplication modulo 8.  $1$ is the identity.  To be a group, each element must have an inverse.  If we imagine starting with the set of numbers $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$,  then we see that $0, 2, 4$, and $6$ do not have inverses: you cannot multiply them by anything in the set which will give an answer of $1 \bmod 8$.  So we are left with $3,5,7$.  Each is its own inverse.  (So each is cyclic with order two - meaning, you multiply it by itself two times and get back to the identity.)  For example, $3*3=9\equiv 1 \bmod 8$.
So the elements of the group $U(8)$ are $1,3,5,7$.  It is of order four, meaning it has four elements.

To be an **automorphism** it must also be an isomorphism.  That means:

$$\phi(a * b) = \phi(a) * \phi(b)$$

that is, if we take two elements a and b, we can perform the group operation before mapping or after mapping and get the same result.

For example, if our automorphism map is the $3\to 3,5\to 7$ and $7\to 5$ then, for example we can perform the operation $3*5$ in the original group and get the result $7$, which maps to $5$ in the automorphic group.

Or, we can map $3\to 3$ and $5\to 7$, and perform the operation in the automorphic group, i.e. $3*7$, with the result being $21 \bmod 8 = 5$. We show that this works for all cases, which shows that it is an automorphism.

For the case of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$, the set is $\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ and the group operation $\bmod 8$ addition.  $1,3,5$ and $7$ are generators, meaning that I can take any one of them, add it to itself a number of times, and get the whole group.  For the isomorphism formula above to work, this must also be true in the automorphic group.  Because $1$ is a generator, once I map it to a different generator, I determine the rest of the automorphism.  For example, if I map $1\to 3$, then since $1+1=2$ (original group), and $3+3=6$ (mapped group), I **must** map $2\to 6$.  $1+1+1=3$ (original group), $3+3+3=9\equiv 1 \bmod 8$ (mapped group), so I **must** map $3\to 1$, etc..  So I really have only four choices, $1\to1, 1\to3,1\to 5,1\to 7$, and any one of these gives an automorphism.

Answer (score 0):

every automorphism $\phi$ of a cyclic group generated by a
is completely determined by $\phi(a)$; as a consequence the number of automorphisms of a cyclic group $G$ equals the number of its generators.
Also note that  $\operatorname{Aut}(\Bbb{Z}_n) ≈ U(n)≈ \Bbb{Z}_n^×$